# Problem with genfromtxt opening a table in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

so I am trying to import a three-column table with 600 rows almost but I keep getting the error:

```
<ipython-input-17-0027dec75ca8>:1: ConversionWarning: Some errors were 
detected !
    Line #2 (got 1 columns instead of 7)
    Line #3 (got 1 columns instead of 7)
    Line #4 (got 1 columns instead of 7)
    Line #5 (got 1 columns instead of 7)
    Line #6 (got 1 columns instead of 7)
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvpSu.png)
[Example of the table I am trying to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cmrb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a comma in the:

```
rc = np.genfromtxt(open('RC.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',', invalid_raise=False).
```

Exactly in Delimiter= ''. This will look like Delimiter= ','

This solved the whole problem I had. Now onto finding other problems xD